# given a circle $(x-1)^{2}+ y^{2}=1$, find $b$ such that the line $y=x+b$ intersects with the circle just once.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

given a circle $(x-1)^{2}+ y^{2}=1$, find $b$ such that the line $y=x+b$ intersects with the circle just once.

This question is for a precalculus class so setting the derivative of the positive half circle equal to one is not how I am trying to go about this.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this basically with only knowledge of algebra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the equation $y = x + b$, so substituting this into the equation for the circle will give you a polynomial in $x$.

That is, 
$$
(x-1)^2 + (x+b)^2 = 1
$$

Solving this for $x$ will generally give you two roots, but there exists $b$ such that there is only one unique root.

Comment: @Ishfaaq The two roots give not the tangent lines themselves, but the points at which the line $y = x+b$ intersects the circle. When the polynomial has only one unique root, the line will be tangent to the circle (and there are two ways to do this, corresponding to tangency above and below)

Comment: So solving for $x$ yields $x=\frac{1}{2}(1-b+ \sqrt{-b^{2}-2b +1})$ (ignoring the negative square root).How do I find this unique $b$ from here?

Comment: @MichaelCromer I have to say I don't think it will really work. Would you kindly show me what does that polynomial stand for?

Comment: @Tim You need to find $b$ such that the positive and negative roots are the same. That means finding $b$ such that the quantity under the square root is zero.

Comment: @Vim The set of points on the circle satisfy $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$. The points on the line satisfy $y= x+b$. To satisfy both means that $(x-1)^2 + (x+b)^2 = 1$, i.e. $y$ is given by the equation for the line. Now we can solve to find the values of $x$ which this occurs at, as a function of $b$. We get two distinct values for $x$ if we take generic $b$, but we can vary $b$ to find values for which only one distinct value of $x$ occurs.

Comment: @MichaelCromer Thank you soooooooo much!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MichaelCromer Thank you. This seems quite novel to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: "intersecting just once" means the line must be tangent to the circle, say, its distance to $(1,0)$ is right the radium $1$. Then, how to express the distance using $b$?